# What is the difference between early career research positions

Tags: postdocs, early-career

I am looking for the differences between the following positions:

1. Researcher
2. Postdoctoral fellow
3. Postdoctoral researcher

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46950/postdoctoral-job-search-positions-and-job-titles/46956#46956

Comment: Also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/who-actually-is-a-post-doctoral-fellow/23898#23898

Comment: Which country? "Researcher" does not sound like a particularly specific term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Researcher may be a permanent position (or not). Post docs are usually term limited and possibly renewable, but not likely indefinitely.

But I imagine that different institutions may use them interchangeably for things that are pretty similar.

Some postdocs actually do a bit of teaching and advising, and in that case, might not be best described as "researchers", but I don't think there is any universally valid terminology for these things.

But each offering announcement should make clear what the expected duties are and, how free you will be, or not be, to carry out your own research.